# Why do I get a 404 GET request error on my computer but I can send my React code to my boss and he does not?

Tags: python, reactjs, json, frontend, http-status-code-404

Error in Browser:

> App.js:20 GET http://localhost:5000/api/private/retrieve-applications/ 404 (Not Found)

Browser Response:

`{detail: "Not Found"}`

Okay so I'm building a web app with python backend and React frontend, my boss built out the backend and created the frontend wireframe on his computer, pushed it to gitlab and I pulled both. I built out the frontend to how we want it and pushed to gitlab. When he starts everything on his computer and pulls up the app he has no errors, no 404 or nothing. When I pull up everything on my computer I have the 404 error above and i get this response in the browser:  {detail: "Not Found"}.  I'm a new developer and haven't worked with Python yet, mostly a React guy. So do I need to install something on my side or maybe there is a npm install command for python? I have python version 3.8.10 installed.

Comment: Assuming you start the python backend, can you browse to that URL?  Perhaps there is a firewall issue that your boss has enabled a port for that you have blocked.

Comment: When I browse that URL with the backend started, it responds that {detail: "Not Found"} and thats all it says. Is there a way to tell if I have firewall restrictions or not?